# File.Exists false when created by tesseract

Tags: c#, captcha, tesseract

I use tesseract to get text from captcha image.
I use this code

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/app/tesseract.exe");
p.StartInfo.Arguments = imgSavePath + " " + txtSavePath;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
bool exist = File.Exists(txtSavePath);
```

The **txtSavePath** is created in windows explorer, i can open it and can read the text in it. But the **exist** variable is **false**. It is so strange. 
Can anybody tell me why? How can i use **StreamReader** to read text in created file?

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract appends a ".txt" extension to the output text file; so in your case, it should be:

```
bool exist = File.Exists(txtSavePath + ".txt");
```